# Only my landlord's bedroom and my bedroom power trips but everywhere else is fine

Tags: electrical

So I moved into a new house, where my landlord lives upstairs and I live downstairs. My brother and  I both have gaming computers, My brother's rig is way stronger than mine, but in the bedroom he was in, the power would cut out randomly and my landlord's bedroom power would cut out as well. It turns out that my landlord and my brother's room are both connected to the same breaker of the room. Our landlord has his AC on most of the time, and my brother plays video games most of the day. Eventually this started to happen more often, in which my brother decided to switch rooms with me to at least lower the load of the room. But only after 3 days, the power tripped again in the same room even with my weaker gaming computer.

The weird thing is that sometimes my brother's computer was under load playing games while my landlord had his AC during his gaming sessions and it never trips the power.

Literally the only thing I have plugged in my room is

1. Gaming Computer (Under Load draws about 250-300 Watts)
2. Two monitors
3. Mouse and Keyboard
4. Controller
5. Internet Router

My landlord primarily has his AC plugged into his room since he needs it due to being about 30+ Celcius in our area.

What I know from the landlord is that the house is old, and this specific room had problems with power cuts at times.

Is it really our two rooms (My room and my landlord) drawing too much power? Even after switching rooms?

A faulty wire due to the house age?

Comment: Who pays the power bills? I'm always suspicious when a landlord is using the same circuits as a tenant, but that might reasonably happen in a house-sharing rather than apartment arrangement...

Comment: It's obvious that you are overloading the circuit. Figure out the amps of all the loads, figure out the amps of the circuit, and discontinue or move loads until you have brought circuit load to under 80% of the breaker trip value.  That's a Code requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Breakers usually trip for two and half reasons.

One is a short in the wires/devices, can be bad. Getting check and fix yesterday is good.

Two is an overload on the wires, why ACs should on their own circuit without other stuff also. Do not put a bigger breaker in, ACs don't put out fire that well.

The half reason is that the breaker is old/weak.